proper thermostat
I switch from heat to cool with a switch at the furnace. Have two normal thermostats upstairs for two zones. Last year gas company switched out one with a digital one that had a heat and cool setting on it. It was winter at the time and he said in the summer just move it to cool and it will work the AC. Well it doesn't I called them back and they moved some wires and got it to work but now that therm. is controlling both zones when I pointed this out he said the damper was stuck open, I check and it was not.  My question is do they sell a regular thermostat with no ac/heat switch on it like I used to have that will do the job

Sounds like you have multiple issues.  But to answer your (not really a) question, yes, there are thermostats that have an AUTO setting.

Can you post photos of all the control wiring involved, as well as the make/model of your zone board?

Please better describe the switch that you switch between seasons.  What does it switch, what model is it, how is it wired?   And the "normal" thermostats .. what model are they and what settings to you have them on?  Are they ones with an "Auto" mode,  and are you using that?  If so, I don't know why you would need to switch a switch in the basement.  And if they are not Auto, I don't see how any switch in the basement could do what you want, unless maybe you've rigged a circuit to reverse the thermostat commands in the summer.

In any case, with most new thermostats, you can control heating and cooling from the thermostat without extra switches.  You may need to run new wires to the stat from the heater and A/C.
